# Using PHP variables for website navigation

Tags: php, if-statement, web, navigation, include

I've used this method on a few website builds with no obvious problems. But I'm wondering if it's an okay/proper way to utilize PHP variables as website navigation/page indicators so that site-wide changes can be easily managed in 1 file (upper.php)? Are there any drawbacks? Maybe too many requests to the server, load times, improper coding or negative S.E.O. ramifications?

I've omitted surrounding code such as < body >, etc. for simplicity and indicated where more code would be with "**...**"

**index.php**

```
<?php $urhere="home"; include ("upper.php"); ?>
    <div>This is the Home page content</div>   
...
```

**about.php**

```
<?php $urhere="about"; include ("upper.php"); ?>
    <div>This is the About page content</div>
...
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php $urhere="contact"; include ("upper.php"); ?>
    <div>This is the Contact page content</div> 
...
```

**upper.php**

```
...

<meta name="description" content="
    <?php
        if ($urhere=="home") echo "Home page description";
        if ($urhere=="about") echo "About page description";
        if ($urhere=="contact") echo "Contact page description";
    ?>

...

<title>
    <?php
        if ($urhere=="home") echo "Home page Title";
        if ($urhere=="about") echo "About page Title";
        if ($urhere=="contact") echo "Contact page Title"; 
    ?>
</title>

...

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/home"<?php if ($urhere=="home") echo " class=\"urhere\""; ?>>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about"<?php if ($urhere=="about") echo " class=\"urhere\""; ?>>About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact"<?php if ($urhere=="contact") echo " class=\"urhere\""; ?>>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some serious maintenance problems with this approach.

Every time you add a new page, you have to add three (for now) if-statements.

**upper.php** knows too much about other pages -- their window titles and metadata.

I would suggest that instead of using the `$urhere` variable to make all the decisions in **upper.php**, you set variables, like window title and metadata, which can be directly used by **upper.php**. Here's an example:

**upper.php**

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description ?>"/>
...
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
...
<?php
$pageTypeToLinkMap = array(
    'home' => array(
        'url' => '/home',
        'linkText' => 'Home'
    ),
    'about' => array(
        'url' => '/about',
        'linkText' => 'About',
        'sublinks' => array(
            'who-we-are' => array(
                'url' => '/who-we-are',
                'linkText' => 'Who We Are'
            ),
            'what-we-do' => array(
                'url' => '/what-we-do',
                'linkText' => 'What We Do',
                'sublinks' => array(
                    'business' => array(
                        'url' => '/business',
                        'linkText' => 'Business'
                    ),
                    'technology' => array(
                        'url' => '/technology',
                        'linkText' => 'Technology'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'contact' => array(
        'url' => '/contact',
        'linkText' => 'Contact'
    )
);

function getLinkElement($pageType, array $linkData)
{
    $class = $urhere == $pageType ? 'urhere' : '';
    $anchorElement = "<a href=\"$linkData[url]\" class=\"$class\">$linkData[linkText]</a>";

    if (isset($linkData['sublinks']))
    {
        $sublinkElements = array();

        foreach ($linkData['sublinks'] as $sublinkPageType => $sublinkData)
            $sublinkElements[] = getLinkElement($sublinkPageType, $sublinkData);

        $sublinksListElement = '<ul>' . implode($sublinkElements) . '</ul>';
    }
    else
        $sublinksListElement = '';

    return "<li>$anchorElement$sublinksListElement</li>";
}
?>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($pageTypeToLinkMap as $pageType => $link) echo getLinkElement($pageType, array $link); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$pageTitle = "Home";
$description = "This is home.";
$urhere = "home"; // I guess you still need this variable to make decisions in the "nav" div.
?>
<div>This is the Home page content</div>
```

**about.php**

```
<?php
$pageTitle = "About";
$description = "About us";
$urhere = "about";
?>
<div>This is the About page content</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

In response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667541/using-php-variables-for-website-navigation/18668020?noredirect=1#comment27507952_18668020), here's how you can improve your **upper.php** while keeping the same original structure:

**upper.php**

```
<?php
$titles = array(
    'home' => 'Home page Title',
    'about' => 'About page Title',
    'contact' => 'Contact page Title'
);

$descriptions = array(
    'home' => 'Home page description',
    'about' => 'About page description',
    'contact' => 'Contact page description'
);

$linkClasses = array_fill_keys(array_keys($titles), '');
$linkClasses[$urhere] = 'urhere';
?>

...

<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $descriptions[$urhere] ?>"/>

...

<title><?php echo $titles[$urhere] ?></title>

...

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/home" class="<?php echo $linkClasses['home'] ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about" class="<?php echo $linkClasses['about'] ?>">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact" class="<?php echo $linkClasses['contact'] ?>">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There you go, if-less code.

Comment: Very interesting. So when new pages are added the only code that has to be added is in the upper.php in the $$pageTypeToLinkMap array, correct? The nav ul builds itself?

Comment: The problems I see are that the title and description have to be edited in each page file, instead of all in the 1 upper.php file. And what about having a nested menu with submenus?

Comment: Moving titles and descriptions to more relevant files shows better separation of responsibilities. If you consider switching between files to be a problem, why not put all of your application code in one single file? I will let you ponder over that. Can you elaborate on what you meant by having nested menu with submenus?

Comment: I disagree about the separation of responsibilities - the pages have all of the content and the upper.php handles all of the <head> and navigation, so it's clean and easy to edit everything quickly. By nested submenus I just meant a submenu nested in the menu, so `<ul><li>About<ul><li>Who We Are</li><li>What We Do</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: I updated my answer to include sub-menus. I see your point about having upper.php handle all the <head> content and making individual pages unaware of it. Can't say it's wrong and although your intention does make sense to me, your implementation can be improved. Instead of having the same kind of if-statements at multiple points, use an associative array whose keys are page types ("home", "about", etc.) and value against each key contains data related to that page type. You can then output title, for example, with `$array[$pageType]['title']`. Set `$pageType` in PHP file of every page.

Comment: I would also recommend taking a look at some PHP MVC frameworks that are specially made to give a good structure to your website.

Comment: Thanks again Omer. Can you provide a more detailed example of the associative array method you touched on in your previous comment? I'm a PHP novice (obviously, haha) but that sounds like the answer/solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Omer. I've implemented that code in a test and like how it works but have a few questions/troubleshoots - what is this section doing? `$linkClasses = array_fill_keys(array_keys($titles), '');
$linkClasses[$urhere] = 'urhere';` and I'm getting class="urhere" on all the nav links, not just the active page?

Comment: I updated the answer to fix that error with class attributes. `array_keys($titles)` returns an array of all the keys in the `$titles` array. `array_fill_keys(array_keys($titles), '')` returns an array which has the same keys as the `$titles` array but value against each key is an empty string. `$linkClasses[$urhere] = 'urhere';` sets `"urhere"` as the value of the key which is equal to `$urhere`. Related reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

Comment: This is looking good. I had to make a slight change to the `$linkClasses[$urhere]` part to have it so it only applies a class to the active page link otherwise the other links had an empty class attribute.

Comment: Last question and I'll definitely be marking this as the accepted answer to my original post (I really appreciate your help): how can I make it so that `class="urhere"` is given to the ABOUT link even when the page (the $urhere) is a sub-page of ABOUT. I've setup a JSFIDDLE to show all of the code (of upper.php) together and I've added "who", "what", "where" in a novice way that I thought it might work, but doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/codeview/tSFgG/2/

Comment: To achieve that, `$urhere` will not be enough (unless you want to resort to ugly conditionals, of course). You will have to add a new variable `$navigationLink` in your specific page files. `$navigationLink` will contain a key of `$linkClasses` denoting the link that will get `class="urhere"`. So in "who", "where" and "what" pages, set `$linkClasses = 'about'` and change the statement `$linkClasses[$urhere] = 'urhere';` to `$linkClasses[$navigationLink] = 'urhere';`. In "home", "about" and "contact" pages, set `$linkClasses` to `'home'`, `'about'` and `'contact'` respectively.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how "keys" work :( So would who.php, what.php, where.php have code like this?: `<?php $urhere="who"; $navigationLink=[$linkClasses];$linkClasses="about"; include ("upper.php");
?>`

Comment: No, this: `<?php $urhere = 'who'; $navigationLink = 'about'; include 'upper.php'; ?>`

Comment: ugh! I'm getting Undefined variable errors now. I've setup a new jsfiddle to show what I have. Any ideas?: http://jsfiddle.net/codeview/qzwVH/

Comment: In index.php, don't set `$linkClasses`; set `$navigationLink`.

Comment: Oh, in your earlier comment you said to set `$linkClasses` to `home`, `about` and `contact` respectively. I've changed `$linkClasses` to `$navigationLink` in index.php now...which fixes that page. But on who.php I receive this error in the meta description and title areas: `Notice:  Undefined index: who in upper.php on line 19 and 20`

Comment: So it's not liking these 2 lines now: `<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $descriptions[$urhere] ?>"/>' '<title><?php echo $titles[$urhere] ?></title>`

Comment: Sorry about mistyping in my earlier comment. That notice occurs because there are no entries for "who" in `$titles` and `$descriptions` arrays.

Comment: If I change those to `<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $descriptions[$navigationLink] ?>"/>` `<title><?php echo $titles[$navigationLink] ?></title>` everything works as it should...but then what's the point of the `$urhere` variable?

Comment: No, that's not correct. Use `$descriptions[$urhere]` and `$titles[$urhere]` but add new elements in `$titles` and `$descriptions` arrays for each new page. Please read the PHP documentation on arrays whose link I gave in one of my previous comments.

Comment: Ah...gotcha! Doh! Thanks so much for your time on this. Answer selected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong way to build a webpage, and there are many options.  In general, I like to use a templating system of some type, which makes the design of the page easy to seperate from the business logic behind it.

1. You could try something like Smarty (http://www.smarty.net/crash_course).
2. Check out some of the awesome MVC PHP Frameworks.  There is a good comparison of the MVC PHP frameworks at the site below

http://jonathanmh.com/best-php-mvc-frameworks-of-2013/